# SQL Query error in JSF, JPA application

Tags: java, jpa

I have a problem with a query in my application. This is the query method doing the query:

```
public List<Product> obtainProductListByCategory(String category)
   {
      Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM PRODUCT p WHERE CATEGORY='" + category + "'");
      List<Product> ret = query.getResultList();

      if (ret == null)
      {
         return new ArrayList<Product>();
      }
      else
      {
         return ret;
      }
   }
```

And this is the error: `javax.ejb.EJBException`

And in the trace I found:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE CATEGORY='Humano']. [22, 22] A select statement must have a FROM clause. [7, 7] The left expression is missing from the arithmetic expression. [9, 22] The right expression is not an arithmetic expression

Any ideas? My objective is to refresh a JSF datatable in my webpage.

---

Edited my code based on @Ilya's answer, and now I got this exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
>   Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT p FROM PRODUCT p WHERE CATEGORY='Humano']. 
>   [14, 21] The abstract schema type 'PRODUCT' is unknown.
>   [30, 38] The identification variable 'CATEGORY' is not defined in the FROM clause.

---

As requested by @Ilya, I post my `Product` class:
EDIT: Added @Table to the annotations.

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Table
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable, IProduct
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Id
   private String name;
   private int stock;
   private float price;
   private String category;
   private String description;

  @Override 
  public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }


  public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


   public Product()
   {
   }


   public Product(String name, int stock, float price, String category, String description)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.stock = stock;
      this.price = price;
      this.category = category;
      this.description = description;
   }





   @Override
   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }


   public void setName(String name)
   {
      this.name = name;
   }


   @Override
   public float getPrice()
   {
      return price;
   }


   public void setPrice(float price)
   {
      this.price = price;
   }


   @Override
   public int getStock()
   {
      return stock;
   }


   public void setStock(int stock)
   {
      this.stock = stock;
   }


   @Override
   public int hashCode()
   {
      return name.hashCode();
   }


   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object object)
   {
      if (!(object instanceof Product))
      {
         return false;
      }
      Product other = (Product) object;
      if (name.equals(other.getName()))
      {
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public String getCategory()
   {
      return category;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      return "Marketv2.model.Product[ name=" + name + " ]";
   }

}
```

Thanks for the help so far. Here I post another query in my application, which is working properly:

```
   public void removeProduct(Product g)
   {
      Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM BasketItem x WHERE x.product.name = '" + g.getName() + "'");
      List<BasketItem> bItems = q.getResultList();
      for (BasketItem i : bItems)
      {
         em.remove(i);
      }

      q = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Product x WHERE x.name = '" + g.getName() + "'");
      q.executeUpdate();
   }
}
```

Comment: Please **do not** delete the older problems, otherwise the answers that tried to solve that problem become invalid. Just add the relevant info to the specific problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1) You should specify alias for tables in `FROM` clause, and `SELECT` clause should contains alias
`Product` should be an entity

```
em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.category='" + category + "'");
```

If `PRODUCT` isn't an entity, you should create `nativeQuery`

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT p FROM PRODUCT p WHERE p.CATEGORY='" + category + "'");
```

[EntityManager::createQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String%29) is for JPQL (Java Persistence query language)
[EntityManager::createNativeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) is for SQL

2) JPA throws the `"Unknown abstract schema type"`  error when JPA fails to locate your entity class
Also add entity to persistence.xml

```
 <persistence-unit ...>
        <class>com.package.Product</class>
```

3) Add `@Table` annotation to your `@Entity`
4) As I see in [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2524), JPQL is case-sensitive.

> With the exception of names of Java classes and properties, queries
>   are case-insensitive. So SeLeCT is the same as sELEct is the same as
>   SELECT, but org.hibernate.eg.FOO and org.hibernate.eg.Foo are
>   different, as are foo.barSet and foo.BARSET.

So JPQL query should be

```
SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.category = '...
```

Comment: Just edited my question, and changed the code to what you suggested. I'm getting a new error now.

Comment: @JeanCarlosSuárezMarranzini is `Product` an entity? Add `Product` class

Comment: It would be better to add parameters using named parameters instead of just adding their values naively like this. Note that these leaks make your application open to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @JeanCarlosSuárezMarranzini JPA will throws the `"Unknown abstract schema type"`  error when JPA fails to locate your entity class

Comment: @JeanCarlosSuárezMarranzini Do you have this class in `persistence.xml`? Is this class mapped during deployment? (see application server's logs)

Comment: @Ilya working on the solution, I'll answer back asap.

Comment: @Ilya Edited question. So far I've applied patch 1 and 3 from your answer. But the 2nd step is a bit confusing to me. I'm able to do other queries based on the product table, but not this one. Is there something weird with this query in particular?

Comment: @JeanCarlosSuárezMarranzini may be case-sensitive parser is used. Try `SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.category=' ...` instead of upper-case

Comment: @Ilya I think that last one did the trick. I still have a problem, where I get this message in the browser: "Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/marketplace.xhtml' for action '#{productManager.getProductsByCategory}' with outcome '[Marketv2.model.Product[ name=Test4 ]]'" is this JSF related or does it have something to do with java code?

Comment: @JeanCarlosSuárezMarranzini This is new problem, and should be investigated

Comment: @Ilya another question I guess?

Comment: @JeanCarlosSuárezMarranzini yes